# CUSTOM UNIQUE CHECK POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a task where I need to store the interviewer's time slot in the table INTERVIEW_SLOT. The table schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE INTERVIEW_SLOT (
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    INTERVIEWER INTEGER REFERENCES USERS(ID) NOT NULL,
    START_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- start time of interview
    END_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, -- end time of interview
    IS_BOOKED BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F', -- slot is booked by any candidate or not
    CREATED_ON TIMESTAMP,
    -- interviewer can't give the same slot twice
    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_INTERVIEW_SLOT UNIQUE (start_time, INTERVIEWER)
);
```

We want to ensure that the interviewer can not give the same slot twice but the problem is with second and millisecond values of start_time. I want the UNIQUE_INTERVIEW_SLOT constant like this:

```
UNIQUE_INTERVIEW_SLOT UNIQUE(TO_TIMESTAMP(start_time::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), INTERVIEWER)
```

Is there any way to add a unique constraint that ignores the second and millisecond value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)

```
create table interview_slot 
(
  id integer primary key generated always as identity,
  interviewer integer references users(id) not null,
  start_time timestamp not null, -- start time of interview
  end_time timestamp not null, -- end time of interview
  is_booked bool not null default 'f', -- slot is booked by any candidate or not
  created_on timestamp,
  constraint unique_interview_slot 
    exclude using gist (interviewer with =, 
                        tsrange(date_trunc('minute', start_time), date_trunc('minute', end_time), '[]') with &&)
);
```

This prevents rows with overlapping start/end ranges for the same interviewer. The timestamps are "rounded" to the full minute. You need the extension [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) in order to create that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`UNIQUE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html) to make this check for you and [`truncate`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) the timestamp to minutes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_interview_slot_ts 
ON interview_slot (interviewer, date_trunc('minutes',start_time));
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8e1f365c00a6018bb57cf0e8b8c2b969)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it works I want a solution that does not use an index.

Comment: @KetanSuthar there is no mention of such restriction in your question - which is quite unusual btw :D. Unique indexes are the standard approach to apply such checks: the docs say  *"Indexes can also be used to enforce uniqueness of a column's value, or the uniqueness of the combined values of more than one column."*. Other than that you'll have to rely on extensions like `btree_gist` or even redesign your data model.

Comment: If you don't want to use the UNIQUE INDEX syntax, you can use the ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT syntax to create the constraint. However, adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the constraint.